# Auto filling form from database access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm using a form for licenses where you need to enter the number of contract, date of contract, owner of license, license start date and end date. But some of the contracts have 50 licenses on it.  My question is; how can I make it so that when I enter a contract number that is already in database, all the fields I mentioned before will automatically fill up to make the data entry quicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AfterUpdate event of the Contract Number, run a query against your dataset.

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ContractNumber = '" & Me.txtContractNumber & "'")

If rec.EOF Then
Else
  Me.LicenseOwner = Rec("LicenseOwner")
  Me.LicenseDate = rec("LicenseDate")
  Etc...
End If
```

Obviously you need to change the table and field names to what you actually have, but that's the framework.